# java.lang.NullPointerException with GeoServer, Postgis and openlayer

Tags: xml, openlayers, postgis, geoserver

I am continuing work that another person began based on Geoserver and postgis. On the database level there are many tables and the layers are views based on these tables. That is working great!

Now I want to create some other tables and views. I have also been adding them to GeoServer. In order to check if this is working I selected the Layer Preview and I clicked on Open Layer in the Common Formats column. The result is that a popup is displayed to download an XML file, but when I open it, it says:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
    <ServiceException> java.lang.NullPointerException null </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

For the layers created by the other person, this works fine. I compared two layers and they seem to be similar, so what am I doing wrong?

PS: All layers are converted from shapefiles to postgis.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the layer you have added in Geoserver does the Native SRS and Declared SRS fields contain values. If they don't then this is probably where your problem is. When adding a table with a geometry field to PostGIS please make sure you specify a SRID so that Geoserver can pick this up for the Native SRS.

If this is the case please check here for a possible fix:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34612/how-to-change-the-srid-of-exisisting-data-in-postgis